# I don't know how to make a user choose an option and output the good result on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming
I started a new project (Quiz Project) on Python
And I use Tkinter for graphic interface
So, I want that when I ask a question to the user, he choose the right one, and I will output "Great", else output "False, try again", all that with Tkinter

If I am not understood, I will show a little example.
Example :
Who slapped Chris Rock at the Oscars ?
• Willow Smith
• Will Smith
• Jaden Smith
Choose the correct answer !

So right now, if he chooses Will Smith, it shall output "Great", else "False, try again"

Sorry, If I did some mistakes in my sentence.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. That said, one way to do something like this would be to make each choice a `tkinter.Radiobutton` and the question itself a `tkinter.Label` widget.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that easily with a combobox.  Check out the following example.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



def analyze():
   selection = combo_box.get()
   combo_box.delete(0, tk.END)

   correct_answer = "Will Smith"

   if selection == correct_answer:
      label["text"] = "Great!!"
   elif selection != correct_answer:
      label["text"] = "False, try again"
   



name_list = ["Willow Smith", "Will Smith", "Jaden Smith"]

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.resizable(False, False)

question_label = tk.Label(root, text="Who slapped Chris Rock at the Oscars?")
question_label.pack()

combo_box = ttk.Combobox(root, font=20, state="normal")
combo_box['values'] = tuple(name_list)
combo_box.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, bg="green", width=10, text="Enter", command=lambda: analyze())
button.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, font="times 16")
label.pack()




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's a problem with "question.pack()", this is what they say : <<NameError: name 'question' is not defined. Did you mean: 'askquestion' ?>> What should I do?

Comment: In the example I gave you it is question_label.pack() and there are no errors, it runs fine.  The question is presented to the user with a tkinter label.   If you don't provide a sample of your code that's giving you the error I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just put in a label and then configure that label again and again using the `configure()` function. For instance:

```
r = Tk()


def check_answer(option):
    result = Label(r, font="Arial 22", text="")
    if option == True:
        result.configure(text="Great!!!")
        result.grid(row=2, column=0)
    else:
        result.configure(text="False, try again!!!")
        result.grid(row=2, column=0)


qst = Label(r, text="Who slapped Chris Rock at the Oscars?", font=("Arial 20", 20))
qst.grid(row=0, column=0)
op1 = Button(r, text="Willow Smith", font="Arial 16", command=lambda: check_answer(False))
op2 = Button(r, text="Will Smith", font="Arial 16", command=lambda: check_answer(True))
op3 = Button(r, text="Jaden Smith", font="Arial 16", command=lambda: check_answer(False))
op1.grid(row=1,  column=0)
op2.grid(row=1, column=1)
op3.grid(row=1, column=2)

r.title('Quiz')
r.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use one `Label` widget `configure` instead of duplicates.

Change this to improve readability.

```
def analyze():
   selection = combo_box.get()
   combo_box.delete(0, tk.END)

   correct_answer = "Will Smith"

   if selection == correct_answer:
      label["text"] = "Great!!"
   elif selection != correct_answer:
      label["text"] = "False, try again"
```

To:

```
def analyze():
    selection = combo_box.get()
    combo_box.delete(0, tk.END)

    correct_answer = "Will Smith"

    if selection == correct_answer:
      answer = "Great!!"
    else:
       answer = "False, try again"
    label["text"] = answer
```